# NiaPy framework - Simple example return me an error

Tags: python, frameworks, runtime-error

I'm trying to implement nature inspired algorithms and I found NiaPy micro-framework for Python.
I installed it (successfully) then I tried the first basic example from here: https://niapy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html.

When I run the script I receive this error message

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 9, in <module>
    algorithm = GreyWolfOptimizer(10, 20 , 10000, 'pinter')
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (5 given)`

I just follow the procedure, do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you have made any mistake in installing NiaPy on your computer or importing it into your program. The error message denotes an error while creating the object. It denotes that arguments supplied to **init** function of your class are greater than required. I can help you resolving this if you can attach the full Python code with it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the traceback, you have installed one of the release candidate (rc) versions of NiaPy framework (e.g. 2.0.0rc4) and then copied the basic example code from the documentation for stable version 1.0.2 of NiaPy framework.

To make the example work, you have two options. You can either install the latest stable version of NiaPy using `pip install NiaPy` or you can change the example code to work properly as is, for example, [shown here](https://github.com/NiaOrg/NiaPy/blob/master/examples/run_gwo.py).

[Here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RgnOaufVxXWiWuly0EypdA4Y6eccJO6K) you can take a look at the Python notebook showcasing basic example for the both mentioned options.